# JDBC dirver SSL error

Tags: android, ssl, jdbc

Я использую драйвер Microsoft jdbc driver sqljdbc41.jar для подключения к MS SQL Server 2016. При попытке подключения получаю следующую ошибку:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed".
ClientConnectionId:52952a1e-b75b-4fdc-b7ae-81d8578b23ee.
```

В чем проблема? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: this is ruSO, so only questions in Russian could be accepted, please translate to Russian or delete your message

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Возможно тут вы найдёте ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766114/sql-server-jdbc-error-on-java-8-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connect